# nosetests - output of `all_config_files` and `user_config_files`

Tags: python, nose, nosetests

I have the following directory structure:

```
main/
    |setup.cfg
    |foo.cfg
    |tests/
          |setup.cfg
          |foo.cfg
          |test_simple.py
```

And test `test_simple.py`:

```
from nose.tools import *
from nose.config import all_config_files, user_config_files

def test_singe():
    print 'all:', all_config_files()
    print 'user:', user_config_files()
    assert_true(False)
```

From `main/` I run `nosetests tests/test_simple.py` and I get:

```
all: ['setup.cfg']
user: []
```

I thought either `all_config_files` or `user_config_files` will return all configuration files. But I get only the top `setup.cfg`.

According to the [docs](https://nose.readthedocs.org/en/latest/api/config.html):

```
all_config_files()
    Return path to any existing user config files, plus any setup.cfg
    in the current working directory.

user_config_files()
    Return path to any existing user config files
```

I would expect files `main/tests/*.cfg` to be found. What is wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the [source code](https://github.com/nose-devs/nose/blob/master/nose/config.py), `user_config_files` will just return configs from user's home folder:

```
config_files = [
    # Linux users will prefer this
    "~/.noserc",
    # Windows users will prefer this
    "~/nose.cfg"
    ]

...

def user_config_files():
    """Return path to any existing user config files
    """
    return filter(os.path.exists,
                  map(os.path.expanduser, config_files))
```

`all_config_files` will return `user_config_files` + setup.cfg from the root dir (where you run nosetests):

```
def all_config_files():
    """Return path to any existing user config files, plus any setup.cfg
    in the current working directory.
    """
    user = user_config_files()
    if os.path.exists('setup.cfg'):
        return user + ['setup.cfg']
    return user
```

Hope that helps.